# Why do third party SDKs throw errors when on our VPN?

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate, vpn

Our application utilizes a number of third party services. I've recently noticed that while connected to our organization's VPN and testing using an emulator, these services fail to operate and log errors in the console.

**Some examples**:

Amplitude:

> com.amplitude.api.AmplitudeClient: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

NewRelic:

> com.newrelic.android: Failed to retrieve collector response: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

> com.newrelic.android: HarvestConnection: Attempting to convert network exception javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException to error code.

Zoom's SDK is also used, and it's initialization callback will indicate an error.

After disabling the VPN on my local machine and restarting the emulator and application, these services will begin to work properly.

I've looked into [the SSL related documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl), but these failures are occurring in third party services, and as such some of the suggestions are not relevant. Additionally, it would seem odd to have to need to modify application code for an issue that happens in a development environment.

I've spoken with our IT team and have obtained the certificates we use, and have attempted to add them to the trusted certificates list in Android Studio via Preferences -> Tools -> Server Certificates. Additionally, I've attempted to manually import the certificates into the `cacerts` truststores in the various JRE/JDK installations on my machine. Both of these modifications did not seem to resolve the issue.

**Questions:**

1. Why are these issues occurring, and how can they be resolved?
2. I've been told similar issues are also being seen by our iOS team. Is it possible that the changes needed are on the VPN or infrastructure side of things instead of the clients?

Comment: This question seems like the sort of professional-network-administration question that would be a better fit for Server Fault, rather than a programming question for Stack Overflow.  I'd expect you to find more people familiar with these topics there as well - you'd probably have better luck there.

Comment: @RyanM The errors described are occurring in an Android application in an Android emulator. There have been no indications that the issue is due to an upstream network misconfiguration. As such, I must assume the issue is strictly client side. Additionally, I have had moderate success by adding certificates to `res/raw/` and referencing them in a `network_security_config.xml` file inside a `debug-overrides` element. This seems to have alleviated the `CertPathValidatorException`s being thrown, but does not appear to fix the issue entirely. This supports the theory that the issue is client side.

Comment: It sounds your VPN does [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) SSL connections. I expect some of these services are using certificate pinning.  Do other apps on these devices also have issues - or are these not general-use devices that need to work with other apps?

Comment: @RyanM Yes, I believe it does "man-in-the-middle SSL connections". I was told the system and certificates are set up in a way that outgoing packets can be decrypted and inspected for sensitive information. The device I am testing on is a freshly created default Pixel 3 emulator. Some of the default apps work (Google Maps) though some show errors (Youtube logs a `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` and visiting any common website using the default Chrome app results in a "Your connection is not private..." page).